# deploy multiple instances of mojolicious app

Tags: perl, web-deployment, mojolicious, plack

I have developed a Mojolicious app on Windows XP, strawberry perl 5.14.2 and Mojolicious version 3.84. For high performance i want to create multiple instances of this app and listening on different ports but same computer. To achieve that i made two copies of my program and used Plack::Middleware::Proxy::Loadbalancer script like this below:

```
use Plack::Builder;
use Plack::App::Proxy;

builder {
    enable "Proxy::LoadBalancer", backends => ['http://l27.0.0.1:8080', 'http://127.0.0.1:8081'];
    Plack::App::Proxy->new()->to_app;
};
```

i start the instances on 8080 and 8081 and then start loadbalancer using plackup loadb.pl command. It listens fine on localhost:5000. But strangely when you connect to port 5000 only 8081 comes up, if it switches to 8080 it gives error Bad Gateway. I am newbie in deployment side so need help here. What is causing the http requests to return only from 8081 ? it seems to be network layer error or something else ? Trying apache loadbalancer will be good idea ?

Comment: Are you really sure that the instance that is supposed to listen on 8080 is really running? Use netstat to find out whether that port really is active.

Answer (score 1):

I am also not a deployment guy, but what I can say is this: your deployment stack seems more limiting than helpful at this point. When running under one of Mojolicious' own servers (daemon, morbo, hypnotoad) they are already using a high powered event loop, which you lose by using a plack server. Also under windows you cannot use hypnotoad which does preforking worker processes to allow more load.

I recommend you read though the [deployment section of the cookbook](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#DEPLOYMENT) then deploy using nginx and hypnotoad on a linux server somewhere if possible.